# aggregation fails on nested aggregation field

Tags: elasticsearch

I've this mapping for `fuas` type:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9201/living_team/_mapping/fuas?pretty'
{
  "living_v1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "fuas" : {
        "properties" : {
          "backlogStatus" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "comment" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "dueTimestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "matter" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "metainfos" : {
            "properties" : {
              "category 1" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "key" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "null" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "processos" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "resources" : {
            "properties" : {
              "noteId" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "resourceId" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "user" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to perform this aggregation:

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/fuas/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "aggs" : {
    "demo" : {
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "metainfos"
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "key" : { "terms" : { "field" : "metainfos.key" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

ES realizes me:

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "aggregation_execution_exception",
      "reason" : "[nested] nested path [metainfos] is not nested"
    } ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query_fetch",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ {
      "shard" : 3,
      "index" : "living_v1",
      "node" : "HfaFBiZ0QceW1dpqAnv-SA",
      "reason" : {
        "type" : "aggregation_execution_exception",
        "reason" : "[nested] nested path [metainfos] is not nested"
      }
    } ]
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `"type":"nested"` from your metainfos mapping.

Should have been:

```
"metainfos" : {
    "type":"nested",
    "properties" : {
        "category 1" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "key" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "null" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "processos" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnaks! The trouble is this "mapping" is creating on the fly. So, I'm serializing documents and ES creates the mapping. I don't know whether it's the best option. Each "metainfo" is unique and only has a single value.

Comment: You need to explicitly create mapping for this property then. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html You need to do this before inserting any data!